# Best book for Three-Body Problem

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

Can anybody advise me the most essential reference for the three-body problem?

I need a book with the problem in different system of coordinates and how actually this changes are performed (synodic, Jacobi...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V Szebehely's book is the standard reference. Also check out Koon et al's "Dynamical systems, three body problem and space mission design". The latter is available for free online.